# using wikipedia dataset for pagerank in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, wikipedia, pagerank

I will be doing a project on pagerank and inverted indexing of wikipedia dataset using apache hadoop.I downloaded the whole wiki dump - http://download.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 .It decompresses to a single 42 Gb .xml file. I want to somehow process this file to get data suitable for input in pagerank and inverted indexing map-reduce algos. Please help! Any leads will be helpful.

Comment: If you're looking for information about what page links to other page on the same wiki, then the `pagelinks` dump has that information (you'll probably also need the `page` dump).

Comment: @svick- exactly! but how do i extract those 2 files from 1 large 42 GB .xml file??

Comment: You don't. Just download the two SQL dumps.

Comment: @svick-ok! Also , i need to do inverted indexing for which i need the whole wikipedia articles. how do i get that??From that large file i downloaded or from any other separate file???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your own Inputformat to process XML. You would also need to implement a RecordReader to make sure your inputsplits have the fully formed XML chunk and not just a single line. See http://www.undercloud.org/?p=408 .

Comment: OK! now i get it! Will try to implement it soon :). Thanks!. Also, is there any software that can open/edit this large .xml files(42 GB)???

Comment: Editing 42 GB file in a single machine would be painful (that's why we use MR). If you want to extract some sample to understand how the xmls look like, try unix head or more commands.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear to me. What kind of idea do you need?

The very first thing which is going to hit you is how are you going to process this xml file in your MR job. MR framework doesn't provide any built-in InputFormat for xml files. For this you might wanna have a look at [this](https://github.com/whym/wikihadoop).

Comment: I wanted to know how i could extract the pagelinks.sql.gz and page.sql.gz files from this big file . these two file contains all i need for input to pagerank!